# Capture requests for image in assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to store an image in my Rails app, hand out the direct URL for it and capture the requests for it.

I have a created a controller/action `images_controller#show`, a layout file with only `yield` and a view file with one single `image_tag`.

The rendered direct link to the image: `https://example.com/assets/a-3883fc3a19a59c2cac8e30c827e81ec6f67538dd0213393d08a425bc800a06a3.jpg`

How would I capture requests for this image as they don't pass the controller? My server logs only shows

> Started GET "/assets/a-3883fc3a19a59c2cac8e30c827e81ec6f67538dd0213393d08a425bc800a06a3.jpg"

Comment: I think there is no way to capture that from within rails application as assets are precomplied and live in /assets directory in root of your site.

Comment: Hm ok. Any other idea how to host an image in Rails and capture the direct requests for it?

Comment: Try something like `carrierwave` gem (https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave). Attach images to model and use the model in requests (e.g. model `Image` and `resources :images` in routes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the "static" assets are placed in the web root of the web server they are served without Rails intervening in production.

In development `config.serve_static_assets = true` is used to get rails to serve assets so that the are compiled on demand. However that would be prohibitively slow in production.

There are two basic alternatives here and which to use depends on your use case:

### 1. Do it on the web server:

This is mostly applicable if uploading the images is a developer concern and you want metrics for technical or marketing reasons.

Both NGinx and Apache can generate metrics for the number of unique visits on a URI. Exactly how to do this depends on your web server / sass provider and the rest of infrastructure in place.

If you decide to go down this route I recommend you start a new question with the details of your setup.

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-target-your-users-with-nginx-analytics-and-a-b-testing
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/shogun

### 2. Handle images as any other resource

If you intend have users upload images you and want tracking or any form of access control you would have the user upload images into a non public directory and serve them through a run of the mill rails controller.

[Gems like paperclip or carrierwave](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/best-rails-image-uploader-paperclip-carrierwave-refile) can make this far easier.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :images

# app/models/image.rb
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :file
end

# app/controllers/images_controller.rb
class ImagesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @image = Image.new
  end

  def create
    @image = Image.new(image_params)
    @image.save
    respond_with(@image)
  end

  def index
    @images = Image.all
  end

  def show
    @images = Image.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |f|
      format.html {}
      format.jpg { send_file @image.file , type: 'image/jpeg', disposition: 'inline' }
    end
  end

  # ...

end
```